# How to compress a PNG image in Flutter?

Tags: android, ios, flutter

I'm new to Flutter. I am trying to compress or resize an image in Flutter, but I always got an unsupported error when the image is in PNG format:

```
Invalid image: ExifInterface got an unsupported image format file(ExifInterface supports JPEG and some RAW image formats only) or a corrupted JPEG file to ExifInterface.
W/ExifInterface(23209): java.io.IOException: Invalid byte order: ffff8950
W/ExifInterface(23209):     at android.media.ExifInterface.readByteOrder(ExifInterface.java:3121)
W/ExifInterface(23209):     at android.media.ExifInterface.isOrfFormat(ExifInterface.java:2437)
W/ExifInterface(23209):     at android.media.ExifInterface.getMimeType(ExifInterface.java:2315)
W/ExifInterface(23209):     at android.media.ExifInterface.loadAttributes(ExifInterface.java:1753)
W/ExifInterface(23209):     at android.media.ExifInterface.initForFilename(ExifInterface.java:2297)
W/ExifInterface(23209):     at android.media.ExifInterface.<init>(ExifInterface.java:1384)
W/ExifInterface(23209):     at io.flutter.plugins.imagepicker.ExifDataCopier.copyExif(ExifDataCopier.java:15)
W/ExifInterface(23209):     at io.flutter.plugins.imagepicker.ImageResizer.resizeImageIfNeeded(ImageResizer.java:41)
W/ExifInterface(23209):     at io.flutter.plugins.imagepicker.ImagePickerDelegate.handleImageResult(ImagePickerDelegate.java:530)
```

I've tried using `image_picker` and `flutter_image_compress.dart` but neither works well with PNG format. It seems these packages only support JPG format. How can I compress the PNG image or somehow convert JPG to PNG?

Here is my code:
By using `image_picker`

```
import 'package:image_picker/image_picker.dart';

    var image = await ImagePicker.pickImage(
        source: ImageSource.gallery,
        maxHeight: 250, // it says this param have compression function but only for JPEG
        maxWidth: 250,
        imageQuality: 90
    );
```

By uisng `flutter_image_compress`

```
import 'package:flutter_image_compress/flutter_image_compress.dart';

//if the original image is PNG, it doesn't work
    var compressImageData = await FlutterImageCompress.compressWithFile( //returns Future<List<int>>
        image_path,
        minWidth: 50,
        minHeight: 50,
        quality: 100,
        format: CompressFormat.png //e.g. compress to PNG
    );
```

Comment: I dont see compressing or resizing an image.

Comment: A .png file does not have an exif header.  A .jpg does.

Comment: the maxHeight and maxWidth parameters in image_picker have the compress function. I also added the code by using image_compressing. png file does not have exlf, so I want to convert it to JPG, is that possible by using flutter? Thanks!

Comment: `// it says this params have compression function but only for JPEG` Well...if the docs say so then you know enough i would say

Comment: For the rest: sorry i do not program with Flutter.

Comment: any update on this, i am also facing same issue ?

Answer (score 0):

Just using new Plugin name : File_support
url : https://pub.dev/packages/file_support

This file support plugin is good when I used first time.It drastically reduce file size 2 mb to 70 kb.

```html
 File compressimage = await FileSupport().compressImage(<Your image file>);
```